# iPhone Cocos2D - facebook, twitter and flickr

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, twitter

I would like to integrate my app with Facebook, Twitter and Flickr. But the kind of integration I want is just to add a button Like, a button to post "I like this app" on twitter and to post screenshots of my app on flickr. I don't want to do anything else on these sites. So, the deal of my app with these sites end when the user does login in their sites.

For example: a link, "post a screenshot of this app" on flickr, would send the user to flickr and send the picture to be posted.

My question is: do I really have to suffer the calvary of creating API keys for all my apps in all these sites I want to interact? Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out addThis http://www.addthis.com/ and the ios sdk http://www.addthis.com/help/ios-quickstart